# I can't get my program to read the values from my input file correctly (2D array)

Tags: c++, input, multidimensional-array, ifstream, file-io

My program reads the values for this incorrectly..
There is the same problem with when I try to get the values from this infile:

14, 14,  8, 0.4, 16,  2.0, 1.7, 7, 4.7, 0.23, 0.44, 290, 350

16, 16, 10, 0.5, 17,  2.2, 1.8, 8, 5.4, 0.27, 0.5, 310, 370

18, 18, 11, 0.5, 18,  2.2, 2.0, 9, 6.0, 0.30, 0.56, 320, 380

20, 20, 12, 0.5, 19,  2.3, 2.2, 9.5, 6.4, 0.32, 0.59, 330, 390

22, 22, 13, 0.5, 20,  2.4, 2.4, 10, 6.7, 0.33, 0.63, 340, 410

24, 24, 14, 0.5, 21,  2.5, 2.5, 11, 7.4, 0.37, 0.69, 350, 420

27, 27, 16, 0.6, 22,  2.6, 2.8, 11.5, 7.7, 0.38, 0.72, 370, 450

30, 30, 18, 0.6, 23,  2.7, 3.0, 12, 8.0, 0.40, 0.75, 380, 460

35, 35, 21, 0.6, 25,  2.8, 3.4, 13, 8.7, 0.43, 0.81, 400, 480

40, 40, 24, 0.6, 26,  2.9, 3.8, 14, 9.4, 0.47, 0.88, 420, 500

45, 45, 27, 0.6, 27,  3.1, 3.8, 15, 10.0, 0.50, 0.94, 440, 520

50, 50, 30, 0.6, 29,  3.2, 3.8, 16, 10.7, 0.53, 1.00, 460, 550

into this code

```
float a [12][13]; //begins the array so the input file can be read

int i, j;

for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
        soft>>a[i][j];
}


int m=0;

while(a[m][0]!= type && m<12)
 {
m++;
 }
bendingStrength = a[m][1];
tensionParallel = a[m][2];
tensionPerpindicular = a[m][3];
compressionParallel = a[m][4];
compressionPerpindicular = a[m][5];
shearStrength = a[m][6];
elasticityParallel = a[m][7];
elasticityParallelFive = a[m][8];
elasticityPerpindicular = a[m][9];
shearModulus = a[m][10];
density = a[m][11];
meanDensity = a[m][12];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float a [6][13]; // Begins the array to read the values from the hardwood file

int i;
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
       hard>>a[i][j];
}
```

The above might work if there were no commas in-between every number , however, your file (at least the one posted above) has all of the values separated by a comma..I believe this is messing up your ability to read in the correct values..(also not sure why you declare `int i;`)

Try code below as an alternative..

```
float a [6][13]; // Begins the array to read the values from the hardwood file

float value;
char comma;
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<13; j++){
       hard>>std::ws>>value; //get value from file ignoring whitespace
       a[i][j] = value;
       hard>>std::ws>>comma; //ignore commas and whitespace
   }
}
```

The second part of your question has the same problems really...you arn't taking into account the commas... You have like before..

```
float a [12][13]; //begins the array so the input file can be read

int i, j;

for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
        soft>>a[i][j];
}
```

You should have...

```
float a [12][13]; // Begins the array to read the values from the hardwood file

float value;
char comma;
for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<13; j++){
       soft>>std::ws>>value; //get value from file ignoring whitespace
       a[i][j] = value;
       if(j != 12){ //dont ignore the comma for last entry on line bc no comma there
       soft>>std::ws>>comma; //ignore commas and whitespace
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, that works for reading that part of the program, I then tried to transfer it to another part of the program which is similar but the input file has more values but it didn't work, this is what that part of the program looks like!

float a [12][13]; //begins the array so the input file can be read

 int i, j;

 for (i=0; i<12; i++)
 {
  for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
   soft>>a[i][j];
 }

 
 int m=0;

    while(a[m][0]!= type && m<12)
     {
    m++;
     }

Comment: Wait, that hasnt come out properly, I will edit my question. Sorry!

Comment: Glad to help, I would love to help more, but several things, First, you should accept an answer to reward the person who helped you since I did solve your original question, Second, it would be better to help you on another completely different question if you would post that question either separately or add the code below the code for your first question so that people who view this question can see what the original question was

Comment: I have made the edits to my answer to help with your second problem

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am very new to this so have no idea what the does and don'ts are! Just done it there, thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry to bother you again but it appears not to work for that part of the program, even thought it worked perfectly for the other part.

Comment: Yea, it runs perfectly now! Yaaay! Thanks!

Comment: awesome sauce glad to help